# Is there an easier way to create this shape with css? (jsfiddle included)

Tags: css, shapes

I am trying to work this shape around an ad but still allow for normal text flow within it. You can see it is a quote and i have been making different id's and class's for curves. So it is really 3 elements with the borders overlapping as of right now but I feel it is making more work than it needs to be.

http://jsfiddle.net/dUKQe/

Comment: Sounds like you need to use a `float`ed element to contain your ad.

Comment: I purposely have the edges running into each other so they overlap. I don't want them to be separate so I was wondering if there was a way to make the border only go a certain distance down the side and then stop

Answer (score 1):

This is not 100% perfect yet (there seems to be some slight pixel variation between browsers to hammer out--I've spent too long on it already), but in general, this gets really close to what you seek through judicious use of pseudo-elements.

[See the example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dUKQe/72/).

**HTML**

```html
<div id="text3" class="text">
    <h4>Bruce Lee</h4>
        <p><q>Be like water making its way through cracks. Do not be assertive, but adjust to the object, and you shall find a way around or through it. If nothing within you stays rigid, outward things will disclose themselves. Empty your mind, be formless. Shapeless, like water. If you put water into a cup, it becomes the cup. You put water into a bottle and it becomes the bottle. You put it in a teapot, it becomes the teapot. Now, water can flow or it can crash. Be water, my friend.</q>
        </p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```css
#text3 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    left: 5px;
    z-index: 0;
}

.text h4 {
    width: 228px;
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #012E40;
    margin: 5px 5px 0 5px;
    padding: 10px 10px 0 10px;
    border: 3px solid #000000;
    border-bottom-width: 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px 5px 0px 0px;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 0px 0px;
    position: relative;
}

.text h4:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 3px;
    height: 3px;
    right: -3px;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: #012E40;
}

.text h4:after { /*upper light blue bkg */
    content: '';
    display: block;
    background-color: #1B4E59;
    border: 2px solid #000000;
    width: 210px;
    height: 3em;
    padding: 5px;
    margin-top: -9px;
    margin-left: 2px;
    margin-bottom: -2px;
    border-bottom-width: 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px 5px 0px 0px;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 0px 0px;
    position: relative;
    top: 10px;
    z-index: 1;
}

.text p {
    color: #ffffff;
    margin: -3em 5px 5px 5px;
    padding: 0 5px 5px;
    width: 448px;
    position: relative;
}

.text p:before { /* inset border corner */
    content: '';
    display: block;
    width: 200px;
    height: 3em;
    float: right;
    margin: -3px 0px 3px 15px;
    border: 3px solid #000000;
    border-top-width: 0;
    border-right-width: 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 5px;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 5px;    
}

.text p:after { /* lower dark blue bkg */
    content: '';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 3em;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin-top: -3px;
    background-color: #012E40;
    border: 3px solid #000000;
    -moz-border-radius: 0px 5px 5px 5px;
    border-radius: 0px 5px 5px 5px;
    z-index: -1;
}

.text p q {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 10px 10px;
    padding: 5px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
}

.text p q:before { /* 2nd inset border corner */
    content: '';
    display: block;
    height: .5em;
    width: 202px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 3em;
    right: 3px;
    border: 2px solid #000000;
    border-top-width: 0;
    border-right-width: 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 5px;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 5px;
    z-index: 3;    
}

.text p q:after { /* lower light blue bkg */
    content: '';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 3.5em;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #1B4E59;
    border: 2px solid #000000;
    border-top-width: 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 0px 5px 5px 5px;
    border-radius: 0px 5px 5px 5px;
    z-index: -1;
}
```